# Update remaining points in different site once purchase through points method

Tags: updating, userpoints

I am using userpoints module. What I need to do is once the purchase is done through points methos, update the remaining points in different drupal site.

I have tried for webservices. I have created web services which will update the remaining points in other site.

I have gone through the code and found function uc_userpoints_payment_uc_order() 'all\modules\userpoints_ubercart\uc_userpoints_payment\uc_userpoints_payment.module' where it updates (uc_userpoints_payment_payment) or refund the points (uc_userpoints_payment_refund). So here (in these two functions), I want to call webservice.

Could anyone please throw some light and point me in right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call web service using `hook_uc_checkout_complete`. it takes action when checkout process is completed.

Please refer [uc_cart api](http://api.ubercart.me/api/drupal/ubercart!uc_cart!uc_cart.api.php/function/hook_uc_checkout_complete/7)